# How to share my IPv6 Internet connection via Wi-Fi from my Windows PC to my Android devices?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ipv6, connection-sharing, ics

According to [Using Wireless Hosted Network and Internet Connection Sharing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815252(v=vs.85).aspx), our Internet connection can be shared to other devices via Internet Connection Sharing and wireless Hosted Networks. However these techniques support IPv4 only seemingly, and the IPv4 addresses of some sites, namely Google, is **blocked** in my location, namely Mainland China. Thence I may only update my Android SDK on my PC but may not update my apps from Play Store.

Therefore it would be very nice to let it work for IPv6 as well as IPv4. Thank you very much!

> PS:
>
> It can be shared with the help of a router and OpenWrt, but it is broken
>
> I'm not looking for a method to access Play Store on my phones, but a more specified and perhaps more interesting one to access it via my PC and the direct connection to Google's servers
>
> Any answers are welcomed, but those without the help of any third-party software or those with the help only from Free Software or Open Source Software are preferred, just by me

Comment: Not sure if this works, but have you tried to connect your phone to your computer via USB in the "debug mode"?

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out as well. I can only get IPv4 or IPv6 connectivity, but not both. Problem is, IPv6-only doesn't work for resolving hosts, so it's pretty useless.

Answer (score -1):

Same problems as you, my solution is to use a router with openwrt installed. See https://github.com/tuna/ipv6.tsinghua.edu.cn/blob/master/openwrt.md for detailed configuration(Since you are in mainland China I think it is not a problem for you to read Simplified Chinese).

Comment: Answers here at Superuser are for everyone, and currently, answers here are suppose to be in English but given all that link-only answers are still frowned upon.